Kafka Topic to MSSQL server via Kafka Connect - Unable to Connect
I am trying to push sample records from the Kafka topic to MSSQL hosted locally via docker.
All the services are running fine but when I try to create a sink connector with the below configuration it throws an error:
{
  "name": "JdbcSinkConnectorConnector_0",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "topics": "test01",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=sample",
    "connection.user": "sa",
    "connection.password": "Admin123",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "table.name.format": "${topic}",
    "auto.create": "true"
  }
}

I refer to this official repo for the docker-compose file. Along with this, I have added the below block in the docker-compose:
mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    container_name: mssql
    user: root
    ports: 
      - 1433:1433
    environment: 
      - SA_PASSWORD=Admin123
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_PID=Standard
      - MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=true
    volumes:
     - ".mssql:/var/mssql"

I am using Azure Data Studio to connect to the MSSQL and I am able to connect and query.
The only problem is when I am using Kafka's control center and trying to push the data generated via KSQLDB. It throws the below error:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused (Connection refused). Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

I am using below code to generate and push data to Kafka topic via KSQL:
CREATE STREAM TEST01 (KEY_COL VARCHAR KEY, COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test01', PARTITIONS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
INSERT INTO TEST01 (KEY_COL, COL1, COL2) VALUES ('X',1,'FOO');
INSERT INTO TEST01 (KEY_COL, COL1, COL2) VALUES ('Y',2,'BAR');
SHOW TOPICS;
PRINT test01 FROM BEGINNING LIMIT 2;

So what am I missing here? I similarly tried Postgres with the below config and it worked well. No errors.
{
  "name": "JdbcSinkConnectorConnector_1",
  "config": {
    "name": "JdbcSinkConnectorConnector_1",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "topics": "test01",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "********",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "table.name.format": "${topic}",
    "auto.create": "true"
  }
}

Please find below details of docker ps command:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                            NAMES
9df3ab7c2b45   confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.7.1   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp                           control-center
b2b62be89f51   confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:7.7.1                "bash -c 'echo Waiti…"   4 hours ago   Up 3 hours                                                    ksql-datagen
e4ec71324a96   confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:7.7.1                  "/bin/sh"                4 hours ago   Up 3 hours                                                    ksqldb-cli
9465e50f88b9   confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.7.1               "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp                           ksqldb-server
f24a78454b0d   cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.6.4-7.6.0   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, 9092/tcp                 connect
44ab10d9aea0   confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.7.1                  "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp                           rest-proxy
44260494a1a2   confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.7.1             "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                           schema-registry
1cbed4ee96c8   confluentinc/cp-server:7.7.1                      "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9101->9101/tcp   broker
d4b9c746cd22   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server                    "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   4 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp                           mssql
0a40688df2a9   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.7.1                   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   4 hours ago   Up 3 hours   2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp       zookeeper

Below are the details of the list of processes tagged to 1433 port:
(base) Downloads % lsof -i:1433
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Microsoft  5986  sid  202u  IPv4 0xcefd609a054dba17      0t0  TCP localhost:56403->localhost:ms-sql-s (ESTABLISHED)
Microsoft  5986  sid  209u  IPv4 0x3ef2d4b92ede00d1      0t0  TCP localhost:55888->localhost:ms-sql-s (ESTABLISHED)
Microsoft  5986  sid  216u  IPv4 0xffb8266d91d81130      0t0  TCP localhost:55872->localhost:ms-sql-s (ESTABLISHED)
Microsoft  5986  sid  221u  IPv4 0xc8b862a268eebba7      0t0  TCP localhost:50971->localhost:ms-sql-s (CLOSE_WAIT)
Microsoft  5986  sid  224u  IPv4 0x48fc815e90723a46      0t0  TCP localhost:51715->localhost:ms-sql-s (CLOSE_WAIT)
Microsoft  5986  sid  235u  IPv4 0x9497d278ff6dfdf7      0t0  TCP localhost:56349->localhost:ms-sql-s (ESTABLISHED)
com.docke 87546  sid    8u  IPv6 0x318017db2858b995      0t0  TCP localhost:ms-sql-s->localhost:56349 (ESTABLISHED)
com.docke 87546  sid  118u  IPv6 0x2b03aa9d6fa879df      0t0  TCP localhost:ms-sql-s->localhost:56403 (ESTABLISHED)
com.docke 87546  sid  129u  IPv6 0x799d7c3441e270bc      0t0  TCP localhost:ms-sql-s->localhost:51715 (FIN_WAIT_2)
com.docke 87546  sid  136u  IPv6 0xdaf881c413e5d1fd      0t0  TCP localhost:ms-sql-s->localhost:50971 (FIN_WAIT_2)
com.docke 87546  sid  153u  IPv6 0xb88afc126a1ddb32      0t0  TCP localhost:ms-sql-s->localhost:55888 (ESTABLISHED)
com.docke 87546  sid  181u  IPv6 0x5300c524e77fa45e      0t0  TCP *:ms-sql-s (LISTEN)
com.docke 87546  sid  187u  IPv6 0x54d6ec9bb58195f5      0t0  TCP localhost:ms-sql-s->localhost:55872 (ESTABLISHED)

Also, here is my docker-compose.yaml file code:
---
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.7.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.7.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.7.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.6.4-7.6.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.7.1.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.7.1
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.7.1
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:7.7.1
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  ksql-datagen:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:7.7.1
    hostname: ksql-datagen
    container_name: ksql-datagen
    depends_on:
      - ksqldb-server
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... && \
                       cub kafka-ready -b broker:29092 1 40 && \
                       echo Waiting for Confluent Schema Registry to be ready... && \
                       cub sr-ready schema-registry 8081 40 && \
                       echo Waiting a few seconds for topic creation to finish... && \
                       sleep 11 && \
                       tail -f /dev/null'"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST: schema-registry
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT: 8081

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.7.1
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
  
  # postgres:
  #   image: postgres:latest
  #   container_name: postgres
  #   restart: always
  #   environment:
  #     POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  #     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  #   ports:
  #     - 5432:5432
    
  
  # pgadmin:
  #   image: dpage/pgadmin4
  #   container_name: pgadmin4_container
  #   restart: always
  #   ports:
  #     - "8888:80"
  #   environment:
  #     PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: siddhesh.s@shellkode.com
  #     PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 1234

  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    container_name: mssql
    ports: 
      - 1433:1433
    environment: 
      - SA_PASSWORD=Admin123
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_PID=Standard
      - MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=true
    volumes:
     - ".mssql:/var/mssql"


If you're using anything newer than about JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server it's likely trying to use encrypt by default, and I would expect to see an exception message related to that (because SQL Server uses self-signed certificates by default). Have you tried adding either ;encrypt=false or ;trustServerCertificate=true to your jdbc:sqlserver:// URI?

I have tried this jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=SAMPLEs;encrypt=false and "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=SAMPLEs;trustServerCertificate=true" but it didn't work. I have also updated the error message in the actual post. I am using personal MAC os and I don't have any firewalls or vpns installed. @AlwaysLearning

I am using Azure Data Studio to connect to the MSSQL and I am able to connect and query. you mean you can access the docker sql server from your host environment? Do you use same localhost? but where is kafka running from?

This is a networking problem.  Is Kafka running in another container?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Every service has been put in a single docker-compose.yaml file.  No service is running separately and yes, I am using ADS to query the MSSQL and it is working fine.

I have also added the details of docker ps command in the post just for clarity

From a networking perspective Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs, meaning that localhost, 127.0.0.1 and ::1 all refer to ports inside the container itself. Since you're trying to connect between containers in a composition have you tried using the container name in the URI yet? i.e.: jdbc:sqlserver://mssql:1433;...

If I use mssql it gives me this error ERROR Not a valid JDBC URL: "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql:1433;databaseName=sample" (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects)

Would the extra_hosts parameter in the docker-compose file help?

ADS works because it is not running in a container; it runs on your host, and you have forwarded port 1433 to your host. Postgres sink worked well because it wasn't using localhost in the URL.
You need to replace the localhost in the URL with mssql.
Please refer https://docs.docker.com/compose/how-tos/networking/
If it still is not connecting, you may need to create/grant users in the MSSQL container for external connections and/or disable encryption, as mentioned in the comments.

If I use mssql it gives me this error ERROR Not a valid JDBC URL: "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql:1433;databaseName=sample" (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects)

I think it's not about connecting error now. It is more related to constructing of the right URL because if it doesn't accept it as URL then I am afraid that it won't even try to connect.

Would the extra_hosts parameter in the docker-compose file help?

@RushHour It's not failing with a network/host error anymore, so no. The URL validity depends on what JDBC drivers are found on the classpath. The container only includes drivers for sqlite and Postgres, by default, and you'll need to mount a volume for any extras. I believe that's mentioned somewhere in the Confluent JDBC connector docs. This is due to licensing restrictions. BTW, Debezium also has a JDBC Sink

I am using kafka-jdbc-sink package. I am using this confluent cli command confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest inside the kafka connect container to install external packages. Once installed I can see the source and sink connector options available in the Kafka Control Center
So what am I missing here? I used the same class/package for Postgres.

In my case, I didn't find any jars apart from the kafka-datagen and monitoring-interceptors jar inside the Kafka connect container. There we no Postgres jars. Once I installed that kafka-jdbc-sink package then only I was able to push the data to Postgres.

@RushHour Once I installed that kafka-jdbc-sink package ... Like I said, that may only include Postgres and SQLite. See https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/jdbc-drivers.html#microsoft-sql-server

Okay, so what am I missing here? I am not able to get your point.

@RushHour You have not shared your Dockerfile, so you'll need to clarify what drivers are available in your container. If the SQL Server / jtds ones are not there, you need to add a new RUN command in the file for wget-ing any additional JAR files. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/extending.html#add-additional-software

I have shared the docker-compose code in the original post. Please let me know what I am missing there.

@RushHour You mentioned you're running confluent-hub commands? Where? The datagen image doesn't install jdbc drivers https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen/blob/master/Dockerfile-confluenthub

I installed it explicitly by entering the container, executing the command, and restarting the services to reflect.

I also used this command to check, and it listed the JDBC source and sink classes. I saw and used it via control center curl -s -XGET http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins%7Cjq '.[].class', but it wasn't present by default.

JDBCConnector is not the same as a JDBC Driver. The REST API will not show installed JDBC Drivers. Restarting the service will delete any manually installed drivers. You must write your own Dockerfile

I see the commands. However, I am unclear about how I integrate with the rest of the services of the docker file.

You would swap out the image of your compose file to no longer use datagen image, but one that you build ahead of time. It'll connect the exact same way.

Okay, if I understand your statement correctly, you mean to build a custom image for datagen and use that in the docker-compose.yaml. Right?

@RushHour Yes, that is exactly what the docs tell you to do, and give an example with MySQL
